# laravel with where clause for prediction

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause

I have 3 table

**student** (has many register)

```
id 
score (NOT NULL)
semester (NOT NULL)
religion (NOT NULL)
```

**program** (has many register)

```
id 
score(NULL)
semester(NULL)
religion(NULL)
```

**register** (belongsto many student and program)

```
id 
student_id
program_id
```

I want to find a student who is predicted to pass the program without the user having to register first with this program. I know its a wrong condition in orWhere, but i have no idea to do it.

```
public function prediction($id)
{
    $program = ReqProgram::find($id);
    $student= Student::where(function($query) use($program){
            $query ->where('score', '>=', $program->score)
            ->orWhere('score', '=', NULL);})
            ->where(function($query) use($program){    
                $query->where('religion', '=', $program->religion)
                ->orWhere('religion', '=', NULL);})
            ->where(function($query) use($program){
                $query ->where('semester', '<=', $program->semester)
                ->orWhere('semester', '=', NULL);})
            ->get();

    return view('kaprodi/prediksi', compact(['mahasiswa', 'program']));  
}
```

I want to find students who have attributes that match the conditions. because table program attributes can be filled with NULL if user don't want to include those attributes as conditions, i dont know how to make it select student that not only,  for example : student.score >= program.score, but if the program.score = null, and then the student will be selected as well. Is it possible? Please, how could i do it? i been stuck so long

Answer (score 0):

These line describe what you want:

```
    $query ->where('score', '>=', $program->score)
    ->orWhere('score', '=', NULL);})
```

Either the score of the student is `NULL` or no less than `$program->score`. However, this won't work. You need to use the `IS` operator instead.

```
    $query ->where('score', '>=', $program->score)
    ->orWhereNull('score'))
```

I cannot say whether your religion criteria is correct.

EDIT: Changed the function call to `orWhereNull` as per https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-for-orwhere-isnull

Comment: is it possible that in the orWhere i can use something like this `orWhere('$program->score, 'IS', null)` ? i know its wrong but do you have the solution to do what with what i mean?

Comment: @YosRafel edited my answer, please take a look at it.